# I use 'wkhtmltopdf' to convert html to pdf,In my html,the image is displayed,however the pdf is not.What is wrong with it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, wkhtmltopdf

This is my gemfile:

```rb
gem 'pdfkit'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf'
```

This is my route.rb:

```rb
get '/pdf' => 'search#pdf'
```

This is my controller:

```rb
def pdf
   render 'pdf',layout:false
end
```

This is my erb search/pdf.html.erb:

```rb
<p>test</p>
<img src="/assets/1.jpg">
```

When I visit 'localhost:3000/pdf', the images can be seen, but for 'localhost:3000/pdf.pdf' they are not shown.

Both of the formats have the `<p>` content displayed but in the html version the image can be seen whereas in the pdf version it can't. What's the problem?

Also, I just found that I can resolve it by using a remote img url. How can I use local images?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
= wicked_pdf_image_tag '1.jpg'
```

Comment: This was my first reaction too but it seems the OP isn't using wicked_pdf. Although arguably it might be worth switching to it.